# Align c++ struct members using vim without plugins

Tags: alignment

Here is a code snippet of c++ source,

```
struct Random
{
   int var1;
   double var2;
   unsinged int var3;
   long long int var4;
}
```

The actual list of struct member I have is very large (over 50 members)
How do I align like below in least amount of key stroke using vanilla vim,

```
struct Random
{
   int                var1;
   double             var2;
   unsigned int       var3;
   long long int      var4;
}
```

Comment: When I'm faced with such issues, I tend to ... write myself a [plugin](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/blob/master/plugin/MoveToCol.vim). And then: `vi{:Align \S\+;$<cr>`